# Exclude node referenced from Related Views

Tags: views, entities

I have a view which show 4 related nodes based on category. Issue is that there is an entity reference product_group, in the node, and I want to show only those nodes which are not in product_group reference field.

This only involves one content type.

Comment: Add the product reference field in the filter criteria and apply "is empty" filter in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis things might be solved in many ways, but the 2 solutions which we can use is.

1. We can add entity reference filter in Filter section of view. Entity Reference Filter is a view of type entity reference, and it should return node id based on arguments, and in our parent view, we can apply condition, that `is not one of`.
2. We can add a contextual filter of NID, with option of provide default value >> fixed value, and under more section, we can check exclude checkbox. After that we can use `hook_views_pre_view`, to set the argument, if it is first contextual filter, then using $arg[0], if it is second contextual filter, then using $arg[1].